# Current haskell platform missing forkFinally

Tags: multithreading, haskell

I just installed the latest haskell platform the other day and can't manage to find forkFinally in Control.Concurrent, I have forkIO and was able to just steal the code straight from hackage for it and it works fine:

```
forkFinally :: Exception e => IO a -> (Either e a -> IO ()) -> IO ThreadId
forkFinally action and_then =
  mask $ \restore ->
    forkIO $ try (restore action) >>= and_then
```

Anybody have any tips or clues what's going on here? Hackage and all my searching seems to indicate forkFinally should be a standard part of the default Control.Concurrent module that comes with the platform...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of base is 4.6.0.1; the current Haskell Platform (2012.4.0.0) comes with base-4.5.1.0. `forkFinally` was new in base-4.6.0.0.

[Link to `Control.Concurrent.forkFinally` in base-4.6.0.0.](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Control-Concurrent.html#v%3aforkFinally)

[Link to `Control.Concurrent` in base-4.5.1.0.](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.1.0/doc/html/Control-Concurrent.html) If you search the page, you will find that `forkFinally` is absent.

Comment: Ahh thanks! I presumed the latest haskell platform would have the latest libs as well (or at least more recent than this, it looked like forkFinally went in several months ago..)

Comment: For libraries that come with GHC (such as base), the Haskell Platform uses the version that comes with GHC. And it doesn't automatically use the latest available version of GHC --- it uses the latest version of GHC that's been out for a while (a few months) and proven itself to not contain any nasty bugs. (Disclaimer: this is my impression, I am not a Haskell Platform maintainer, I don't speak for them, etc.)